# Levitating boy grounded

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, powers

This would be a short story (turned out to be a novella), probably late 70' or early 80's. It involved three boys from three different alien (to each other) races. One of the boys belonged to aliens who had psionic powers, and he never walked anywhere, he always levitated.
The boys get in trouble over something and the levitating boy is 'grounded', ie forbidden by his parents from using levitation for a while, and thus forced to walk. Which obviously made hm unhappy.
That is literally all I remember about it.

Comment: Ah man... I know this one. I just can't place the name. It's set in sort of a rural community.

Comment: I want to say that the kid who gets "grounded" is nicknamed something like "Fancy Pants" because he floats to avoid messing up his clothes, and at the end, the protagonist beats him up in revenge for childhood slights. I want to say that the community conflict involves something rampaging through fences or crops.

Comment: That sounds familiar to me too.

Comment: One of many short stories by various authors compiled into a book titled "Tomorrow's Children", edited by none other than Isaac Asimov.

Comment: I marked this a duplicate in the other direction because I feel like the other question wound up with more details, despite coming later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

["No Life of Their Own"](https://archive.org/details/galaxymagazine-1959-08/page/n8/mode/1up?view=theater) by Clifford D. Simak

Summary from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_D._Simak_bibliography)

> Aliens are settling local farms, so Steve plays with kids nicknamed Fancy Pants, Nature Boy, and Butch. Quarrels escalate when one boy goes missing, and only kids can see the ghostly "Halflings" who hold him!

From the story:

> Up by the barn, I saw Fancy
> Pants limping along on the ground.
> He was having a tough time walking. But I didn't feel the least bit
> sorry for him. He had it coming.
>
> I figured in just a little while I'd
> go up around the barn and clobber
> him for that time he mopped up
> the road with me.
>
> It should be an easy job, I told
> myself, with him grounded by his
> Pa for thirty days.

Found with a search for `short story aliens in a farming community`, which had an except from [*Aliens in Popular Culture*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Aliens_in_Popular_Culture/lvaKDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=short+story+aliens+in+a+farming+community&pg=PA228&printsec=frontcover) from which I searched for `simak alien children farming`, which brought me to the Wikipedia article.

Comment: I wonder where I read it. I'll have to read the other stories in that magazine to see if I remember them at all. Thanks.

Comment: I remember it from "Tomorrow's Children", edited by Isaac Asimov. It's an anthology of short stories by a wide variety of authors.

Comment: That might be where I read it. It's rather amazing how much those children seem like yesterdays children: from when I was a kid or even before.

Comment: @VaughnOhlman:I know I read that anthology as a child, so I probably read it there too. :) Probably also came up on my initial searches, but I didn't recognize the title of the story based on the contents.