# Short story, all characters young, apparently male. One character floats in air, another is teddy bear

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, young-adult

This could be anywhere from say 1970 or so to 1983. Book, probably hardcover, collection of short stories.

All characters young, apparently male. One character floats in the air, and is insufferably smug, another is a teddy bear, and the protagonist seems to have been simply a human boy, but I'm not sure.

Somehow the floating boy pulls some sort of very nasty trick on the human boy. All goes badly for a while, but then the floating boy is discovered as the culprit. As punishment, the floating boy's dad says he will be "forced to walk on the ground for an entire month".

The story ends with the human boy thinking with great satisfaction that now he can go beat up the floating boy.

Comment: This may be Phillip K. Dick’s short story _The Little Movement_, first published in 1952 in The Magazine of Fantasy & Science Fiction. Some features: Toys plot to take over world decide to focus on only kids. Protagonist is a normal boy. Key toy is Teddy Bear, Teddo. An airplane flys but no floating toy that I recall.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Borrowing from my answer to [Levitating boy grounded](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/250718/23243):

["No Life of Their Own"](https://archive.org/details/galaxymagazine-1959-08/page/n8/mode/1up?view=theater) by Clifford D. Simak

Summary from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_D._Simak_bibliography)

> Aliens are settling local farms, so Steve plays with kids nicknamed Fancy Pants, Nature Boy, and Butch. Quarrels escalate when one boy goes missing, and only kids can see the ghostly "Halflings" who hold him!

Butch is human. Fancy Pants is from an alien race that has telekinesis and float. And Nature Boy has fur all over him (the "teddy bear").

From the story:

> Up by the barn, I saw Fancy
> Pants limping along on the ground.
> He was having a tough time walking. But I didn't feel the least bit
> sorry for him. He had it coming.
>
> I figured in just a little while I'd
> go up around the barn and clobber
> him for that time he mopped up
> the road with me.
>
> It should be an easy job, I told
> myself, with him grounded by his
> Pa for thirty days.

If I recall correctly, the "nasty trick" involved using telekinesis to suspend a dog and a cat in the short next to each other so that they couldn't escape, and tore at each other to get away.

There's not enough data to speculate on [where you read it](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?57022), but I read it in *[Tomorrow's Children](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?51964)*.

Comment: This is the right answer! Yep, back then I was reading everything with the word "Asimov" anywhere on it. Thanks!